# How to declare a constant that can be accessed by multiple viewcontrollers in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, constants

I have an app I'm working on that has various viewcontrollers that use the same constants.

ex.

```
let wrongAnswerBanner = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "torn_banner"))
```

I tried declaring the constant outside the viewcontrollers but whenever I try to call the constant by using self.

```
self.wrongAnswerBanner.hidden = false
```

I get the error: Value of type 'ViewController1' has no member 'wrongAnswerBanner'. How can I declare these constants without having to redeclare them within each individual viewcontroller?

Comment: create a class or struct with constants

Comment: `UIImageView` isn't a very good constant, since various of its properties (specifically its `superview` and `frame`) are likely to change while the app is running…

Comment: What do you recommend then in this type of situation?

Comment: Each view controller should create the wrong answer banner when it needs it. If there's a lot of common configuration of it, you could create a XIB containing the image view, or factor out the code into (for example) an extension on UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Create a struct with constants:

```
struct Constant {

    static let SomeConstant = "hey"

}
```

then you can get the value from any class by

```
let constant = Constant.SomeConstant
```

Comment: Didn't think of using a struct, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the constant outside of a class scope and access it directly from any file inside the module.

File 1

```
let MyConstant = "MyConstant"
class A {

}
```

File 2

```
class B {
    // use MyConstant directly (eg. print(MyConstant))
}
```

I usually do this for `UITableViewCell` identifiers. I declare them on top of my `UITableViewCell` subclass and use them on the ViewController file. It's worth nothing though (as other developers mentioned) that `UIImageView` might not be a good candidate for constants. You can also make use of Enums if that makes sense for your problem.

Comment: I tried doing that but anytime I used self within a function in the view controller I would get the error: Value of type 'ViewController1' has no member '....'.

Comment: You mean you are trying to do self.MyConstant? You can't use self since the constant is not in fact a member of any class. Just simple use MyConstant. Eg. `label.text = MyConstant`.

Comment: So what if I wanted to do something like self.wrongAnswerBanner.hidden = false  but inside the viewcontroller?

Comment: That's the point, `self` doesn't have a reference to wrongAnswerBanner. If I may, I suggest you to not use a constant for that scenario since you want to have a reference for the banner and want to manipulate it's state.

Comment: So do you think the best course of action is to redeclare the UI constants in each individual view controller?

Comment: For UI constants – yes

Comment: Ok, in what type of circumstances do you think its safe to declare a global constant outside the viewcontrollers?

Comment: When they are really constants , a.k.a. not subject to states like your example is (hidden, not hidden, added to a view, not added to a view etc.). As I said in my answer, I use this approach for cell identifiers.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, also a view can have only one parent, if you tried to add this banner on another view it would disappear from the previous one. It's probably not what you want. It's a good hint it doesn't make sense to make a constant of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to call the constant without `self`

Answer (score 0):

According to me you have to create one AppConstant.swift file in your application ,then just add this line in AppConstant.swift file

let wrongAnswerBanner = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "torn_banner"))

Then in any of controller you can easily access **wrongAnswerBanner** without using self